# AssertionError for feast materialize command

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, assertion, feature-store, feast

I am trying to configure Feast with PostgreSQLSource as both online and offline source. I have created a table in db and edited feature_store.yaml file with proper credentials. I can successfully generate feature views and deploy infrastructure.
But when I run feast materialize command, it throwing an AssertionError for offline_stores. What might be the possible error/mistake and how can I resolve it??

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue recently, I tried using postgresql as datasource, online store and offline store by editing feature-store.yaml file. Postgres supported as Registry, Online store, and Offline store is now available officially in feast version [0.21.0](https://github.com/feast-dev/feast/compare/v0.20.0...v0.21.0).
So if you use old version for postgresql then you will face issue and instead of editing feature-store.yaml just use postgres as template while feast init.

Refer:
https://github.com/feast-dev/feast/releases